# Rear wheel wobbles

Tags: wheels, repair, rear-wheel

my rear wheel wobbles while it spins, like in this [video](http://youtu.be/v410LNTDan8?t=1m42s).
I read in the comments that it could simply be a badly mounted tire. What's your advice on this, what should I do?

Comment: The wheel is out of true. What you need is a spoke wrench at the minimum to true it. This basically means that some spokes are either too tight or too loose. A truing stand could also be handy if it is within your budget.

Comment: Either the tire has been mounted lopsided or the wheel is out of true.  If it's simply the tire you can deflate it and straighten it -- it should straighten up with a few tugs.  If the wheel is out of true it must be "trued", a conceptually simple operation but one that requires some mechanical ability.

Comment: thanks for all your comments. I took it to a repair shop and the guy adjusted the spokes. I'm glad I took it there as it spared me some frustration, but next time I really wanna try myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video indicates the wheel is out of true. It can be a real hassle trying to true the wheel yourself if you don't have proper equipment and the experience to perform the job. I suggest a trip to the local bike shop and allow an expert to save you some frustration. It shouldn't be that expensive because your wheel isn't all that bad. At least it turns and that's better than some wheels I've seen!

Comment: The wheel may also be as true as it's going to get depending on how badly the rim has been bent. Sometimes there's only so much you can do. Or you may get it true, but out of dish.